# Cross-sections of a revolutionplot3D of a piece-wise function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I trying to get multiple cross-sections of a revolution plot I made from a piece-wise function.

The end goal would be to calculate integrals underneath those cross-sections.

my code looks like this:

```
Table[RevolutionPlot3D[
Piecewise[{{2^(0.4 x), 0 < x < 10}, {5 x - 50, 
10 < x < 13}, {5 x - 65, 13 < x < 16}}, Exclusions -> None], {x, 
0, 30}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[f]], 
PlotLabel -> f], {f, {0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1}}]
```

My approach was to use RegionFunction, but it neither gave me the cross-sections that I wanted nor was I close to calculate any integrals. Should I try a completely different approach or does anyone have some an idea how to improve my code?

An example of an cross-section that I am interested in [image: cross-section]

Comment: Give an example of a cross section you seek.

Comment: Basically anywhere on object else than through the middle. A cross-section going through the middle would just give the piecewise function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you wish to use [`SliceContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html)

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{2^(0.4 x), 0 < x < 10}, {5 x - 50, 
    10 < x < 13}, {5 x - 65, 13 < x < 16}, {0, True}}, 
  Exclusions -> None]
Manipulate[
 SliceContourPlot3D[
  f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] - z, {v == p}, {x, -16, 16}, {y, -16, 16}, {z, 0,
    16}, Contours -> {{0}}], {v, {x, y, z, x + y}}, {p, -5, 5}]
```

[image]